# Get percentage for progress bar with Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, progress-bar

I've started learning Vuejs and as a newbie i've started with some basic stuff like fetching data from an API and presenting data to a template. It works fine till now but i had an idea of setting a progress bar. So every time a record is added in db, then increase progress in percentage meaning one record in db 1%, 2 records 2% and so on until reaching 100%.
My problem is to calculate the percentage, I did some research but i couldn't find something similar to this, so if someone can give me some instructions on how to do it, i would be very pleased!
Below is my code so far.

```
<div class="mt-5">
 <div class="mt-2 mb-3 w-full">Progress of Goal: 
  <span class="text-indigo-600 font-semibold">{{ salaries.length }}% - {{ salaries.length }} Salaries submitted</span>
 </div>
 <div class="w-full bg-gray-200 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-500">
  <div class="bg-purple-600 text-xs font-medium text-blue-100 text-center p-0.5 leading-none rounded-full" style="width: 4%"> {{ salariesLength }}%</div>
  </div>
 </div>     
</div>
<div class="is-loading-bar has-text-centered" v-bind:class="{'is-loading': $store.state.isLoading}">
 <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
</div>
<div
 class="flex flex-col xl:flex-row justify-center items-stretch w-full"
 v-for="salary in salaries"
 v-bind:key="salary.id"
>
<SalaryItem :salary="salary" />
/div>

<script>

  import axios from 'axios'
  import SalaryItem from '@/components/SalaryItem.vue'
  
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        salaries: [],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      salariesLength() {
        return this.salaries.length
      }
    },
    components: {
      SalaryItem
    },
    async mounted() {
      this.$store.commit('setIsLoading', true)

      await axios
        .get('/salaries/')
        .then(response => {
          this.salaries = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      
      this.$store.commit('setIsLoading', false)

    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand on what total the percentage in calculated on the example you provided : you seem to fetch all data at once in your mounted hook, on what base do you want to define percentage ?

Besides that, you can render a progress bar by setting dynamically the width property of your progress bar element using a computed :

```
  computed: {
    progressStyle() {
      return {
        width: this.progress + "%",
      };
    },
  },
```

In your template, you just declare 2 elements : one container and inside your progress bar that will have a width expressed in % of the container:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="progress-bar" :style="progressStyle"></div>
  </div>
```

Through the `:style` attribute, the width of the div will be *x%* depending on the `progress` variable that you need to define to handle the logic to calculate the percentage. Again, Im not sure where you get your total from, so we'll have to assume a `totalSalaries` exists somewhere :

```
computed: {
    progress(){
      return this.salaries.length / this.totalSalaries * 100
    },
    progressStyle() {
      return {
        width: this.progress + "%",
      };
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for your the detailed explanation and sorry if my description wasn't quite clear! I set totalSalaries and percentage works as expected!